# How can I change my visa appointment to another country?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm moving to another country before the appointment.

When I login to my visa account, I don't see an option to change the country. Only city.

Comment: What country's visa are you trying to obtain? What is your citizenship? Where are you moving from? Where are you moving to?

Comment: Please, i was looking for the visitors visa interview appointment, finally saw one on the 05/05/2023 and i wanted to schedule because my program is on the 27/05/2023, but just after doing the payment, i went to schedule appointment i saw but a different date, which is not even within my program. please what can i do

Comment: @SONESERGEEJOLLE You need to ask a separate question. You won’t get an answer from posting a comment in someone else’s question

Answer (score 11):

Presuming that both of the US Consulates in the countries you're trying to change from and to both use the ustraveldocs.com/CGI Federal website (as most but not all countries do), then you will need to open a support request with them to have your "profile" changed between countries.

Alternatively you might be able to create a new account with them using a different email address, however if you've already entered your passport details on the website for the original country then this will NOT work without manual intervention, so it's not generally a good idea.

Note that any fee payments you've made will NOT transfer between the two countries, so if you've already paid the fee for the appointment you will need to pay it again in the new country - which may be difficult depending on which country it's in (eg, some require it paid locally using cash, whilst others allow the use of credit cards)

Comment: Why do I need to pay again? If I'm paying again, there's no point in moving the existing interview to another country.

Comment: You need to pay again because each country has their own method of payment. That's just how it works...

Answer (score 7):

@Doc is right, and thanks!

For me, I have an account registered in another country. I need apply the visa in a different country Korea.

I went to US embassy in Korea website at https://www.ustraveldocs.com/kr/kr-main-contactus.asp
and clicked "LIVE CHAT" button. After talking about my situation with the representative, she helped me transfer my account to Korea.

[image]

After transferring, I can still sign in using same account at https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/

My appointment history in old country is still there. Then when I schedule a new appointment, it will show locations in Korea.

Comment: this also worked for me for Switzerland / Romania